# Analyse frequencies of date ranges

Tags: google-sheets, date

I have a Google Spreadsheets where I would like to compute occurrences of date ranges. I have a column `date_utc+1` which contains almost random date data.

What I would like to do is put the date values into bins of six hours each, i.e., `12/5/2012 23:57:04` until `12/6/2012 0:03:17` would be in the first bin, `12/6/2012 11:20:53` until `12/6/2012 17:17:07` in the second bin, and so forth. Then, I would like to count the occurrence of those bins, such as:

```
bin_from            bin_to                freq
-----------------------------------------------
12/5/2012 23:57:04  12/6/2012 0:03:17     2
12/6/2012 11:20:53  12/6/2012 17:17:07    19
...                 ...                   ...
```

Partial hints are very welcome as well since I am pretty new to spreadsheeting.

Comment: Try reading this question & answers: http://superuser.com/q/518632/179112

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra - Does that work for Google Spreadsheets?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra this actually exactly solves my question http://superuser.com/questions/519286/compute-number-of-occurrences-in-a-column-of-a-spreadsheet, you could answer it with a link to your answer in the other question or mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @DaveRook; see example file I've included.

Comment: In the future, please ask questions about Google Spreadsheets here, not on Super User. Thanks!

Comment: fixed the error in my sheet...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I've got the solution for you. It's not done all automatically, but it will result in your proposal:

- In your file the date is written as `MM-DD-YYYY`. I made the assumption
  that the date range covers december and **NOT** random dates throughout
  the year. Therefore I had to re-arrange the date format to
  `DD-MM-YYYY`.
- As a guidance I used the following formula to get the unique date
  range: `=UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(DATEVALUE(I2:I)))`
- In the FREQUENCY sheet I used this formula to calculate the first
  interval:
  `='Original Data'!J2+TIME(18;0;0)`
  *You need to choose the intervals wisely.*
- Copy down this formula untill the desired interval range is
  completed:
  `=A3+TIME(6;0;0)`
- Use the [FREQUENCY](https://spreadsheets.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/pub?key=pzLh3kFGO3CxW-ggAWtWeJA&output=html&gid=0&single=true) formula to calculate your result:
  `=FREQUENCY('Original Data'!I2:I;A3:A)`

See example file I've prepared: [Frequencies](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdE41TkxCaldQWExlZk0tQVBoZlFORlE)

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thank you! Last question: How did you easily convert the dates from MM-DD-YYYY to DD-MM-YYYY (I don't see any formula).

Comment: I will add it to the file OK, as a bonus !! Thanks and good luck.

Comment: @wnstnsmth: see sheet DATE

Comment: fair enough.. thought there was a smoother way :-)

Answer (score -1):

Using the [query](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1388882) language and a [group by](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Group_By) clause should do the trick.

Something like:  `=QUERY(A1:A509, "select count(B) group by year(A)")`
I will try to create a working query later today.

EDIT:

I have inserted a new column left of column A. This column has the formula : `=year(A2) & "-" & minute(A2)`. This is just a quick test to create some ranges, this column should reflect the logic of the bins.

The formula `=Query(A:E;"select B, count(A) group by B")` will calculate the frequencies.

-- disclaimer, this is just an example, some tweaking is required to make it calculate the exact functionality mentioned in the question --

Comment: In order for `select count(B)` to work, you need to prepare the range accordingly: `A:B`. Secondly, in Switzerland most probably the semicolon is used in stead off the comma.

Comment: @wnstnsmth and Jasper: I've added the result into the file I created under sheet QUERY.

Comment: @Jacob, I've also completed my solution in the sheet (Columns K,L,M). Any comments on this solution? As my answer was down-voted, I would like to know if I am missing something here.